# The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key

Tags: java, netbeans, prepared-statement, derby, embedded-database

I keep getting this error:

```
Error code 20000, SQL state 23505
Insert command failed: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL160524112023610' defined on 'TEST'.
```

[image]

When I run this code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DerbyBatch {

    private static Connection connection;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            createDatabase();
            createTable();
            insertBatch();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DerbyBatch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void createDatabase() throws SQLException {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:" + new File("test").getAbsolutePath() + ";" + "create=true");
        disconnect();
    }

    public static void createTable() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        connect();
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE \"APP\".\"TEST\" (ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), TEXT VARCHAR (30000) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(createTable);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        preparedStatement.close();
        connection.commit();
        disconnect();
    }

    public static void insertBatch() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        connect();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO TEST (ID, TEXT) VALUES (?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "TEST");
        preparedStatement.addBatch();
        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        connection.commit();
        disconnect();
        Logger.getLogger(DerbyBatch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "All data inserted.");
    }

    public static void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy");
        Connection temp = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:log4jdbc:derby:" + new File("test").getAbsolutePath());
        connection = new net.sf.log4jdbc.ConnectionSpy(temp);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    }

    public static void disconnect() throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

and then try to manually insert a record in netbeans services tab -> databases:

[image]

I made sure that everything is committed and the connection is closed properly so I'm not sure why derby keeps picking up a duplicate index after doing a batch insert?

Comment: i think every time you are inserting the same ID, Which is your primary key.

Comment: cannot reproduce the problem with the given code.

Comment: @Moh-Aw: My derby version is 10.10.1.1, log4jdbc is 1.2, slf4j-api is 1.7.21,  slf4j-log4j12 is 1.7.21

Comment: only difference in my config is derby 10.12.1.1

Comment: @Moh-Aw: Strange, I get it even with the latest. I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2, maybe that's why? Also, I'm using embedded derby

Comment: you are somehow inserting the record twice as @jankigadhiya already pointed out. not sure how. are you omitting any code?

Comment: You are setting the value 1 for the column ID in insertBatch(). That means that Derby isn't generating that column's value; you are setting the value yourself. If it is always 1, you can only insert one row, with the value 1; all others will be duplicates.

Comment: @BryanPendleton: I am inserting the ID myself but it seems as though Derby does not start from the last existing ID after a batch insert but rather just the first ID for some strange reason. I believe it does the same thing even if you try to insert another record after batch through Java instead of Netbeans.

Comment: If you insert the ID yourself, Derby uses what you insert, it doesn't generate an ID. That's what `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` means. If you want Derby to generate the ID, then you should either do `GENERATED ALWAYS`, and never give the ID yourself, or if you want to use `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`, then you need to **NOT** give the ID if you want Derby to generate it for you. IOW, `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` means: "only generate an ID if I don't insert an ID myself".

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here, especially as you had already posted the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`, the assumption that automatically generated values should start from the last existing ID is wrong; they will always start from the `START WITH` value.

So, when you try to insert another row with NetBeans, the automatic ID generation will get triggered for the first time and it will try to insert an ID with the `START WITH` value; since that is `1` like the ID you manually put via Java, it will fail with the duplicate key error.

The [official documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqlj37836.html) also covers your exact case:

> ```
> create table greetings 
>         (i int generated by default as identity, ch char(50));
> -- specify value "1":
> insert into greetings values (1, 'hi');
> -- use generated default 
> insert into greetings values (DEFAULT, 'salut');
> -- use generated default 
> insert into greetings(ch) values ('bonjour');
> ```
>
> Note that unlike a `GENERATED ALWAYS` column, a `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`
>   column does not guarantee uniqueness.
>
> Thus, in the above example, the
>   `hi` and `salut` rows will both have an identity value of `1`, because the
>   generated column starts at `1` and the user-specified value was also
>   `1`.
>
> To prevent duplication, especially when loading or importing
>   data, create the table using the `START WITH` value which corresponds to
>   the first identity value that the system should assign.

So you either don't manually insert IDs and just use the automatic generation, or you change the `START WITH` accordingly to your manually inserted ID, for example `START WITH 2`.

You can also change the `START WITH` value at a later moment using `ALTER TABLE` with `RESTART WITH`; the [documentation of `ALTER TABLE`](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html) has an example that address a situation similar to yours:

> Consider the following example, which involves a combination of
>   automatically generated data and manually inserted data:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE tauto(i INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, k INT)
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tautoInd ON tauto(i)
> INSERT INTO tauto(k) values 1,2
> ```
>
> The system
>   will automatically generate values for the identity column. But now
>   you need to manually insert some data into the identity column:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO tauto VALUES (3,3)
> INSERT INTO tauto VALUES (4,4)
> INSERT INTO tauto VALUES (5,5)
> ```
>
> The identity column has used values `1` through `5` at
>   this point. If you now want the system to generate a value, the system
>   will generate a `3`, which will result in a unique key exception because
>   the value `3` has already been manually inserted.
>
> To compensate for the
>   manual inserts, issue an `ALTER TABLE` statement for the identity column
>   with `RESTART WITH 6`:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE tauto ALTER COLUMN i RESTART WITH 6
> ```

Comment: Do you know if there's a query that can be used to update the `START WITH` after a batch insert?

Comment: @Hooli Yes, you can use `ALTER TABLE` with `RESTART WITH`, I updated the answer adding this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your test will only ever run successfully once. After that it will fail on a duplicate insert, duplicate table create, or something similar unless you drop the created table after the test.

Comment: Do you think derby has a bug where `START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1` gets bypassed when using batch inserts? Perhaps that's why when inserting a record manually after a batch insert it attempts to reuse `1` as the `ID`?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem.  Looking at your table definition, I would actually guess that if you took away the "identity" attribute of your table definition, it would work fine. Many databases don't like manual insertions into identity columns.

Comment: @nerdfest regarding manual insertion into identity columns, there is an important difference between `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` versus `GENERATED ALWAYS`. Here are the docs: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqlj37836.html